# How to get the exponent of a double in a power of 10 in java?

Tags: java, double

(Sorry I don't know what is the best keyword to describe this problem.)

The main problem is, if I have a double number in java, say **25.003**, how can I know that this number can be written in **25003 x 10^(-3)**, **so that I can get the exponent part (-3)**?

**The only thing I desire is to get that exponent number (-3).** (so I know I can multiply 25.003 by 1000 to make it an integer) Is there any method gives me that exponent number?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple if you think of it as a String.

```
private static int getExponentForNumber(double number)
{
    String numberAsString = String.valueOf(number);
    return numberAsString.substring(numberAsString.indexOf('.') + 1).length() * -1;
}
```

This is just returning the length after the "." which is your negative exponent. So you can really just use it like that:

```
int exponent = getExponentForNumber(25.003);
int basis = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(25.003).replace(".", ""));
String expression = "25.003 equals " + basis + "*10^" + exponent;
System.out.println(expression);

25.003 equals 25003*10^-3
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, only fails in the case that the string of a double with no floating part like **15.0 is considered 15 * 10^(-1)**. I am wondering are there any other exceptions? If this is the only exception case then I will use if-else to avoid them :).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It pretty much fails with .0~ - also take care when you have numbers like 0.0001 - this will fail in the basis line.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
private static int getExponent(double number)
{
    String str = String.valueOf(number);
    int pointIndex = str.indexOf('.');
    if (pointIndex == -1  || pointIndex == str.length() - 1)
        return 0;

    while (str.endsWith("0")) {
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
    }

    pointIndex = str.indexOf('.');
    if (pointIndex == str.length() - 1)
        return 0;

    String[] splitted = str.split("\\.");
    return -splitted[1].length();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d1 = 12.36;
    double d2 = .36;
    double d3 = 12.;
    double d4 = 0.101;
    double d5 = 15;

    System.out.println(d1 + " " + getExponent(d1));
    System.out.println(d2 + " " + getExponent(d2));
    System.out.println(d3 + " " + getExponent(d3));
    System.out.println(d4 + " " + getExponent(d4));
    System.out.println(d5 + " " + getExponent(d5));
}
```

prints

```
12.36 -2
0.36 -2
12.0 0
0.101 -3
15.0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Double d = in.nextDouble();
String[] parts = d.toString().split("\\.");
System.out.println(parts[0] + " *10^ -" + parts[1].length());
```